# VerifyError during bean creation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, verifyerror

We use Spring as DI. We have bean with contructor with @Inject annotation. During server start I got VerifyError

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'SomeUsefullBean' defined in "../some.jar/../SomeUsefullBean.class": 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: 
(class: com/someone/SomeUsefullBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd8c2b52_39, method: <init> signature: 
(Lcom/someone/something1;
Lcom/someone/something2;
Lcom/someone/something3;
Lcom/someone/something4;
Lcom/someone/something5;
Lcom/someone/something6;
Lcom/someone/something7;)V) Register 8 contains wrong type
```

I check everything I can remember - library version, java version, Spring version, even run build on another PC. All dependencies was correct, defined and no cycle dependencies were present too. Absolutely normal bean.

Spring version 4.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by removing constructor and replace it with annotated setters. When constructor parameter size exceed some amount (6 in my case) JVM throws VerifyError. I still do not know why it happens and why it affects Spring bean loading. Suppose some bug in bytecode generator. For me WA acceptable and working fine.